# Dynamic property assignment passing interface property

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic, lambda

I have a generic class  with `ICommand` properties. This is a composite object that use as child object that have is hown `ICommand` properties.

I was searching a system to define during runtime the interface to use with this class and the command properties of child object that have to be "used" like the `ICommand` property of generic.

Finally having something like this:

```
    public TestDynamic<T>
    {
        public ICommand ChildCommand;
        public T CompositeChild;
    ...
    }
    public interface ITestOne{
        ICommand DoSomethin{get;set;}
    }
    public interface ITestTwo{
        ICommand DoSomethingMore{get;set;}
    }

    ITestOne MyObj1=...
    ITestTwo MyObj2=...

    TestDynamic<ITestOne> TD1=...
    TD1.DynamicRegistration((i)=>i.DoSomething);  
    TD1.ChildCommand.Execute();//DoSomething execution
    TestDynamic<ITestTwo> TD2=...
    TD2.CompositeChild=MyObj2;
    TD2.DynamicRegistration((i)=>i.DoSomethingMore);
    TD2.ChildCommand.Execute();//DoSomethingMore execution
    //Those are done in a different moment. Where i can't simply set the property
    TD1.CompositeChild=MyObj1; 
    TD1.CompositeChild=MyObj1;
```

Actually with `Action<T,ICommand>` i define a delegate that return the "correct" `ICommand` of child class.

What could be the better way to achieve this in your opinions?

Comment: I've tried to think thru your question but am stuck understanding exactly what you're trying to do. Can you please edit your question and elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you really just want an ICommand that has an Action as a property rather than making some kind of factory.

mvvmlight toolkit has such a command.

[RelayCommand](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5056f53e22e0#GalaSoft.MvvmLight%2fGalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29%2fCommand%2fRelayCommand.cs)

[RelayCommandGeneric](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5056f53e22e0#GalaSoft.MvvmLight%2fGalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29%2fCommand%2fRelayCommandGeneric.cs)